# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: nodejs

```js
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
});
```

Porque sale ese error si el parentesis se esta cerrando aqui `})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque el callback tiene una sintaxis errónea.

**Usando** `function`:

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) { .. });
```

**Usando arrow function (ES6)**:

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

Falta definir la función:

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) { //Aquí!
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
});
```